# Multiple conditions in Bash for outputting error

Tags: bash, if-statement, scripting

My question is similar to ones asked multiple times before. I have a script that checks multiple variables on a machine and logs that data. For instance, I'm checking Firewall and Encryption on the machine, and if one or both of them are off I need to echo exactly what is turned off. I'm looking at using something along the lines of this...

```
if [ $firewall -eq "Off" ] ||  [ $Encryption -eq "Off" ]; then
echo Please fix ****
else
echo "Everything is great"
fi
```

I'm having a problem of how parse out the data in the second line.

**EDIT:** I've gotten some great answers, but the thing I'm curious about is, how would I work it if I have a list of 5 things I'm checking on, and say 2 of them are not meeting the standard. I'd like to output only those that are not passing to the end user so they know what they need to fix?

So given the example above, let's say I'm testing for Firewall, Encryption, Patches, and Disk Space. If the user needs to fix Firewall and Encryption, I'd like to output only those two. If another user has issues with Disk Space, one one to them, and another user has everything okay, then a message that everything is fine.

**EDIT 2:*** I'm pulling the information I require, the only problem is I need to have one of two different pop-up windows. Either one that shows what exactly is wrong, **and that could be any number of things**, or one that shows that everything is working properly.

So far I've come up with the code below, but it's showing me two windows, one that shows the errors, and the other "Everything is great" pop-up in that order. Where am I going wrong?

```
for i in Software Firewall XProtect; do
    if [[ "${!i}" == "Off" ]]; then 
        osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Compliance Check results \r \r'$i' needs attention\r \rPress OK to continue."'
    Elseif
        osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Compliance Check results \r \rEverything looks good. \r \rPress OK to continue."'
    fi
done
```

Thank you in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-eq` is used for Integer comparison only.

Better to simplify your code like this:

```
if [ "$firewall" = "Off" ]; then
   echo "firewall is Off"
elif  [ "$Encryption" = "Off" ]; then
   echo "Encryption is Off"
else
   echo "Everything is great"
fi
```

**EDIT:** To check multiple variable you can use this `for loop`:

```
for i in A B C D; do
    [[ "${!i}" == "Off" ]] && echo "$i is Off"
done
```

Comment: Will this work if I had say, 4 variables, and any combination of one to all 4 of them aren't meeting the criteria? Such as I have variables A, B, C, and D, but B and D are not in compliance. Can I echo out to the user to fix B and D?

Comment: Yes you can do so. If you lots of variable to check then you can also run a for loop to validate. I will edit answer to show how

Comment: I think I get what's going on with the `for loop`, my issue is that I need the output to appear in a text dialog box for the end user to see. Currently I'm blasting out everything the script detects to the user for compliance as follows:

`osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Moka 5 Compliance Check results \r \rSoftware Up to Date: '$suresult' \rFirewall Status: '$fwresult' \rXProtect Status: '$xpresult' \r \rPress OK to continue."'`

Comment: So far I've made it this far...

`for i in $suref $fwresult $xpresult; do
[[ "${!i}" == "Off" ]] && osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog  "'$i' is Off"'
done`

Comment: Instead of `for i in $suref $fwresult $xpresult;` you will need `for i in suref fwresult xpresult;`

Comment: I've made some changes, but I'm still having an issue with the dialog boxes.

Comment: Can you clarify what issues you are facing.

Comment: I'm getting multiple message boxes using the osascript command. When the script runs I get 3 message boxes; one that says everything is okay, then one displaying that the firewall is off, followed by one saying everything is okay. I need to have only 1 message box after the script runs. This message box needs to either show EVERYTHING that is failing compliance, so the user can fix those issues, or display that everything is fine so the user can continue to the program. Is it possible to get everything in the array that is "Off" to show up in a single pop-up message box?

Comment: You can stuff all `Off` value arrays in single array with this: `oarr=(); for i in A B C D; do [[ "${!i}" == "Off" ]] && oarr+=($i); done` But I can only answer you about shell scripting. For dialogue box and osascript related issue I suggest you open a new question to get better answer from SO community.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if [[ ${firewall:-}  = "Off"  ||  ${Encryption:-} = "Off" ]]; then
   echo Please fix ****
else
   echo "Everything is great"
fi
```

Comment: I edited the question to better reflect what exactly I'm looking for. Will this work the way I'm thinking it will?